# silverlight: How to set attached properties Programmatically

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-2.0

Suppose I have a grid with some row definitions, and a child control in that grid.  How would I go about setting the Grid.Row property of the child control programatically?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To set the value:

```
textBlock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 3);
```

To reset the value:

```
textBlock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, null);
```

Comment: If you prefer, you could use the idiom:

Grid.SetRow(textBlock, 3);

Attached properties usually have Get and Set methods (although I don't think it's mandatory so there may be exceptions).

Comment: I notice (this is with the SL3 beta) that to change the location of a child control, you can't just set this property -- you need to remove the control from the parent grid, set the property as shown here, and then re-add it to the parent.

Answer (score 7):

Actually to clear a value you should use this:

```
textBlock.ClearValue(Grid.RowProperty);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure this is in SilverLight, but in WPF you call a static method (called SetX, where X is the property) on the type the attached property is defined on and pass it in which control to set the value on, and the value:

```
Grid.SetRow(MyControl, myRowNumber);
```

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head, you might be able to null it.