# LayoutGrid SetRow and SetColumn not working as intended

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, button

I have code that creates a button for each object in a list.  When each object is created it is given a name that corresponds to the row and column (i.e. name = row1col2).  Each button is generated dynamically, added to the grid and then the row/column are set.  At a later time I need to gather the "selected" button data so I can perform actions on the data they represent.  When I attempt to get the control data from the buttons everything is fine, except for the grid row/column data.  It remains the same for all of the selected rows and columns in a grid.

Creating buttons:

```
for (int i = 1; i < row.StackCount+1; i++)
{
    //create button for the column
    stackButton = new Button();
    stackButton.Height = ((newRow.Height - 2));
    stackButton.Width = ((newRow.Width / row.StackCount) - 2);
    stackButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

    //add the button border
    stackButton.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    stackButton.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
    stackButton.Style = Application.Current.Resources["flatButton"] as Style;

    //add the button name
    stackButton.Name = "Row" + row.LineNumber + "Col" + (i - 1).ToString();

    //add the event handler to the button
    stackButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(stackButton_Click);

    //add a new column
    newRow.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(newRow.Width, GridUnitType.Star) });

    //put the button into the grid
    newRow.Children.Add(stackButton); 
    Grid.SetRow(stackButton, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(stackButton, i-1);
}
```

Getting the Button data back

```
g = (Grid)b.Child;
foreach (Button currentButton in g.Children)
{
    if (((SolidColorBrush)currentButton.Background).Color == Colors.Gray)
    {
        //create a stack object
        buttonData.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        buttonData.LotNumber = LotDisplay.Text;
        buttonData.RoomID = SilverGlobals.CurrentRoom.RoomID;

        buttonData.RoomCol = Grid.GetColumn(currentButton);
        buttonData.RoomRow = Grid.GetRow(currentButton);

        buttonData.TrayCount = int.Parse(currentButton.Content.ToString());
        buttonData.Status = 0;

        //add stack object to list of stack objects
        stacks.Add(buttonData);
    }
}
```

I know this must be something small I am missing.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What values is it returning for each button's row and column?

Comment: Row=0 and Col=3 (there are 4 buttons being processed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the comment in your second section of code says:

```
//create a stack object
```

you don't actually create a new stack object so it is simply overwriting the single instance of `buttonData` on each iteration.  The values for row and column that you see at the end are the last iteration's values.

The net effect is that `stacks` is a collection of all the same instance of an object instead of a collection of separate instances.

Comment: I knew it was something to that effect.  I don't know how I missed that though.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.  I use examples like yours to justify why I don't comment my code.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425537/silverlight-how-to-set-attached-properties-programmatically) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871199/possible-to-programmatically-add-user-control-to-silverlight-grid-column), it might be that you need to set the Row and Column properties *before* you add the button to its parent - something like this:

```
//put the button into the grid
Grid.SetRow(stackButton, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(stackButton, i-1);
newRow.Children.Add(stackButton);
```